# IIS Redirect Help

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, redirect

I built a website (asp.net, c#) years ago for a client of ours.  We're now looking to launch a new website for them.  The current website is hosted on the client's server.  The new website will be hosted on a different server (new IP).  They'd like all the proper redirects in place to ensure search engine ranking.  The URL structure for the existing site is:

Old About Us Page:
www.mydomain.com/Source/Item.aspx?id=about&sid=02

New About Us Page:
www.mydomain.com/about-us.aspx

Old Careers Page:
www.mydomain.com/Source/Item.aspx?id=careers&sid=01

New Careers Page:
www.mydomain.com/about-us/career-opportunities.aspx

As you can see, it's not a 1:1 mapping.

I'm a redirect rookie and not sure about the best way to handle this.  Do I need to redirect to the new site with a 301 in IIS, pass all the query string parameters, handle that with code (in the new site), and send the user to the proper page.  Do I need to write code in the old site that redirects them to the new one?  How will that work if the domain hasn't propagated yet?  Can I handle this in IIS?  Any help or wisdom is appreciated.

Comment: which version of IIS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

in iis it's simple:
http://www.mcanerin.com/en/articles/301-redirect-iis.asp

or if you use asp.net 4.0
Response.RedirectPermanent("~/grass-guzzler-2010.aspx")

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `<httpRedirect>` attribute of IIS?

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect

[EDIT]

I agree with `@Ryan's comment` on my answer.

Bedsides that if you using IIS 7, for more specific need, you can use [Microsoft URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/)

Comment: I have, but due to my ghetto URL structure I think I need to apply logic before redirecting...

Comment: I'd give the httpRedirect attribute a 2nd look.  It's extremely powerful, and you can get to the level of just redirecting specific URL's.  It's all regex based so you can do some pretty powerful expressions to do your redirects.